# Handling Many to many , 1 to many relation ship between dimensions

Tags: dimensions, datamodel

I have a scenario where one sales guy is related to more than one departments, and I need to calculate the sales at sales rep level and department level. Please share the thoughts on how it can be modelled

My thought process is below

**Option 1**

I will be creating as 'Sales Rep' dimension and 'Department' dimension and connected it with a bridge table which has dept_id and sales rep_id
Here both the dimensions I prefer to have the history so it is SCD type 2

**Option 2**

I will be creating 'Sales Rep' dimension and 'Department' dimension and in department dimension, I will be adding the filed " sales rep id". which connects the Sales rep with Department.T he drawback I have observed here is Department details will be repeating in 'Department' table for each employee.
Here both the dimensions I prefer to have the history so it is SCD type 2

Please share your answer, the above options which one is better, or any other third best approach -

Answer (score 0):

This answer is related to the business model more than to technological needs:
Options 2 makes the best sense if the sales person could belong to more than one department, keep the department at the "sales" fact table, and then no need to keep the department in the "sales person" dimension. 
Option 1 makes the best sense if the sales person belongs only to one department at a time, but he might change departments, make this a Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2 in which you keep the history.

[Slowly changing dimension](http://datawarehouse4u.info/SCD-Slowly-Changing-Dimensions.html) means you don't need a bridge table, the department is part of the "sales person" table, and you can read more about it in the link provided.
In the odd case that a sales person can work in several departments and have people from various departments reporting to him, then all the hierarchical model should be in a different table. In SSAS a self-reflecting table doesn't work well, try to check ways in which to flatten those issues.

Please note that when you're designing a data warehouse the star schema means exactly that: data might repeat itself in different tables in order to make the reporting easier. 
Those issues never have a clear cut solution and I advise you to read as much as you can on data warehouse design until your head spins in order to get your head around this.

Comment: As you said ,if sales person belong to only one department at a time and he can change departments  ,why the the bridge table with M:N relationship is needed ,Department can be part of the 'Sales Rep' declension itself - Could you please clarify on this point . Also my case A sales Supervisor  can be work on multiple departments at a time and many people reports to him as well from various departments . Could you share your thoughts in this case ..

Comment: Hi @sudhi, I've modified my answer to answer your questions, I hope that's clear